# ¿Cómo hacer respaldos automáticos en UNIX?

Tags: apache, servidor, nginx, unix

¿Cómo crear una tarea automática para respaldar mis archivos todos los días a la misma hora? Algo como:

```
rm -rf /var/respaldo/
rm -rf /var/respaldo.zip
rm -rf /var/www/sql/
mkdir -p /var/www/sql/
cd /var/www/sql
mysqldump -u respaldo -pcontraseña pagina.com > pagina.com.sql
mkdir -p /var/respaldo/
cp -r /var/www/ /var/respaldo/www/
cp -r /etc/nginx/sites-available /var/respaldo/sites-available/
rm -rf /var/respaldo/www/html/phpmyadmin/
mv /var/respaldo/www/sql/ /var/respaldo/
cd /var/
zip -r respaldo.zip respaldo
rm -rf /var/respaldo/
```

y que se ejecute todos los días a la misma hora (Ese código yo lo uso para hacerlos, pero me da mucha pereza hacerlo diario, así que a veces pasa un mes sin que haga respaldo)

Gracias por cualquier información

Answer (score 0):

Para automatizar la tarea de respaldo de archivos todos los días a la misma hora, puedes utilizar la utilidad cron en sistemas basados en Unix (como Linux). cron te permite programar tareas periódicas, como la que mencionaste. Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo puedes configurar una tarea cron para ejecutar tu script de respaldo todos los días a una hora específica:

Abre una terminal en tu sistema Linux.

Edita el archivo crontab para tu usuario. Puedes hacerlo ejecutando el siguiente comando:

bash
Copy code
crontab -e
Esto abrirá el archivo crontab en un editor de texto. Añade la siguiente línea al final del archivo para programar la tarea diaria:

bash
Copy code
0 2 * * * /ruta/a/tu/script-de-respaldo.sh
En esta línea, los números representan:

0: El minuto en que se ejecutará la tarea (en este caso, a los 0 minutos).
2: La hora en que se ejecutará la tarea (en este caso, a las 2 de la madrugada).
*: El día del mes (cualquier día).
*: El mes (cualquier mes).
*: El día de la semana (cualquier día de la semana).
Asegúrate de reemplazar /ruta/a/tu/script-de-respaldo.sh con la ubicación real de tu script de respaldo.

Guarda y cierra el archivo crontab.

Con esta configuración, tu script de respaldo se ejecutará automáticamente todos los días a las 2:00 AM. Puedes ajustar la hora y los minutos según tus preferencias.

Recuerda dar permisos de ejecución a tu script de respaldo usando chmod +x /ruta/a/tu/script-de-respaldo.sh para asegurarte de que sea ejecutable. También, asegúrate de que el usuario que configura la tarea cron tenga los permisos necesarios para acceder a los directorios y archivos involucrados en el respaldo.